# Angular CLI build without index.html

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

All our Angular applications are bootstrapped in other applications (`.jsp` files which load the javascript files and include the `<app-root>` tag), so we have no need for an `index.html`**.

However when I remove the `index` property from our `angular.json` it gives me the error:

> Data path "" should have required property 'index'.

If I leave it empty it does build but I get the error:

> ...
>    95% emitting index-html-webpack-pluginEISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
>   Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

How can I perform an `ng build` without the `index.html`?

** our deploy process now actually copies the `index.html` to our CDN which is unwanted since we don't want to serve these files to the end users at all, the `index.html` is only used for developers during `ng serve`

Comment: you need the index.html file as it contains the meta data and bits

Comment: @Aerus, I'm afraid you must to investigate and modify someway the file  index-html-webpack-plugin.js from node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins or another like

Comment: It's a mild annoyance, but I too don't need the index page as my project is used only to build custom elements. It feels like being able to remove the index page should be an option for these types of scenarios.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In case anyone is still having the same issue, this is how I solved it.

In your `angular.json`:

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    ...
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "index": "", // Do not copy index.html
        ...
```

`ng build --prod` will not copy the HTML file, while `ng build` and `ng serve` will keep using it as expected.

Comment: I wasted so many time trying to solve the index.html issue, but that's true, I don't need it in the build, in prod app is loaded in another page. This is a wonderful workaround, thanks @nebirhos

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate commands in the `scripts` section of `package.json`. So append a delete command and create something like this (Windows command; adapt it to your system):

```
"scripts": {
   "build prod": "ng build --prod --env=prod -op dist && del dist\\index.html"
}
```